# How to change characterset in DataGrip?

Tags: sql, utf-8, datagrip

[image: i can't see characters in persian language]
i'm trying many ways butrather the problem is exist.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to change charset or collation of table/column via UI in DataGrip.
You should use MySQL (while you use a MySQL DB) commands via console.
For table:

```
ALTER TABLE books.authors CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

For column:

```
ALTER TABLE books.authors MODIFY Firstname VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Also check which charset is used in the application that inserts data into your DB. Maybe you need to run `SET NAMES` query right after connecting.

MySQL manual about charsets and collations:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-column.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySql Workbench for that